# is used uninitialized in this function

Tags: c

I am having a really difficult time with this function.

```
void GetBaseDeclarationLabel(char *strings_label_table1[], char *strings_mneumonic_table1[],
         char *strings_operand_table1[], int hex_address_table1[], char *base_label)
{
    int i = 0;
    int cmp_str2 = 0;
    //char label[20] = {0}; 
    //int k = 0; 
    //printf(" i is %s \n", strings_label_table1[1]); 
    for(i = 0; i < 503; i++)
    {
        if(strings_mneumonic_table1[i] != NULL)
        {
            cmp_str2 = strcmp(strings_mneumonic_table1[i], "BASE");
            if(cmp_str2 == 0)
            {
                //printf(" ??please?? \n");
                //printf(" hex_address_table1[i] is %x \n", hex_address_table1[i]);
                //strcpy(label, strings_operand_table1[i]);
                base_label = malloc(strlen(strings_operand_table1[i])+1);
                strcpy(base_label, strings_operand_table1[i]);
                //base_label = strings_operand_table1[i]; 
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    //return label;
}
```

This is my initial variable declaration. The reason why I made it NULL is because my warning flags complained it was uninitialized and I had a segmentation fault when I didn't do that. Now that I have done that I can't get my `base_label` to change. I have tried the usual = method, and just for the hell of it I tried the malloc and then strcpy method. Neither method worked in changing the value.

```
char *base_label = NULL;
```

This is how I call the function.

```
GetBaseDeclarationLabel(strings_label_table1, strings_mneumonic_table1,
     strings_operand_table1, hex_address_table1, base_label);
```

Comment: When you declare a variable `base_label` inside the function, it shadows the parameter of that name.

Comment: I declared `base_label` in another function. I wanted to use `GetBaseDeclarationLabel()` function to set it.

Answer (score 8):

If your function shall allocate a buffer and return that buffer, then you need to change the function signature to

```
void GetBaseDeclarationLabel(char *strings_label_table1[], char *strings_mneumonic_table1[],
     char *strings_operand_table1[], int hex_address_table1[], char **base_label);
```

Then you would

```
*base_label = malloc(strlen(strings_operand_table1[i])+1);
strcpy(*base_label, strings_operand_table1[i]);
```

The caller would be changed to

```
char *base_label = NULL;
GetBaseDeclarationLabel(strings_label_table1, strings_mneumonic_table1, strings_operand_table1,
                        hex_address_table1, &base_label);
```

Comment: OMG thank you. I have been banging my head against the wall for like the last 3 hours.

Comment: @cokedude If my answer worked for you it would be nice to accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because in C arguments are passed by value, so if you want to change the value of a variable in a function, you need to pass the address of that variable to that function. So if you want to change the value of a pointer in a function, you need to pass the address of that pointer, a.k.a. a double pointer.

For example,

```
int v;

foo (&v); /* `v` will equals 42 after this */


void foo (int *v) {
    *v = 42;
}
```

Comment: What about when you have a char? I didn't think you could get the address of a char like that?

Comment: @cokedude By `a char` you mean a character literal like `'a'`? `&` only works for variable and function name.

Comment: Like `char *characters`.

Comment: @cokedude Is this `characters` a variable? If it is, then of course you can use `&characters` to get its address.

Comment: characters is a variable. Thank you for explaining. I thought you could only get the address of the number types like int, double, long int, etc.